# Leaflet : TypeError: L.Shapefile is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have been trying to build a Web Map using the Leaflet. One of the tasks that I was trying to execute was adding a "Shapefile" on the basemap. I get the below error in the console when I try to execute the file.

> TypeError: L.Shapefile is not a constructor

I have verified if my shapefile is not corrupt by running it on, 
http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I would genuinely appreciate some guidance, I am new to JavaScript and Leaflet so I may have missed something obvious.

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />

  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet/leaflet.shpfile.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet/shp.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([32.78, -96.80], 11);

  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
      maxZoom: 17,
      minZoom: 9
    }).addTo(map);

  var shpfile = new L.Shapefile("DALNEI.zip");
  shpfile.addTo(map);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: is this the right name of the file: leaflet.shpfile.js?

Comment: I believe so, I referred to a few examples and this is name used. This one,https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/shapefiles-leaflet

Comment: yeah, it is right, but looks weird tho, anyways, another thing i've noticed, looks like you're including leaflet.js twice (from cdn and local copy) any reason to do that?

Comment: No. I didn't realize I was doing that. Thank you. I'll correct it.

Comment: Unfortunately, It still doesn't resolve the main issue that I am facing.

Comment: var shpfile = L.shapefile('file here') (note no new here)

Comment: TypeError: L.shapefile is not a function, This is the error I get get now.

Comment: definitely something wrong with the file you're trying to include there, does it looks like this one? https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile/blob/gh-pages/leaflet.shpfile.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to verify that your `lealet/shapefile.js` is actually loading, as every problem you have so far is indicating it's not at the path you're specifying. Checking your browser console for `404` errors will verify this.

The "not a constructor" and "not a function" errors have nothing to do with the content of your shapefile. They are both saying the properties on `L`, `shapefile` and `Shapefile`, that your are trying to access, don't exist.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. I re-checked all the packages. It loads perfectly now. Thank you !!!